# List grouping dynamically

Tags: c#, list, linq, grouping

I want to group a list that includes integer `List<int>`.

```
List<CNode> cNodes
```

and the CNode is

```
public class CNode
{
    public List<int> Elements;
    // ...
}
```

I can group the `cNodes` like that

```
var groups = cNodes.GroupBy(node => node.Elements[0]);
foreach (var group in groups )
{
    // ...
}
```

but as you see the groupping is depends the first element, I want to group it by all elements

For example if `node.Elements.Count == 5` expected grouping result should be the same as for:

```
var groups = cNodes.GroupBy(node => new
{
    A = node.Elements[0],
    B = node.Elements[1],
    C = node.Elements[2],
    D = node.Elements[3],
    E = node.Elements[4]
});
```

I couldn't find the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Use node.Take(5)

Comment: @jdweng it's not helping.

Comment: I think you want SelectMany   var results = cNodes.SelectMany(x => x.Elements).ToList();

Comment: Do all Elements collections have the same size?

Comment: @alexanderpetrov yes, They are same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `node.Take(5)` with a proper `IEqualityComparer` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cNodes = new List<CNode>
            {
                new CNode{Elements = new List<int>{ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 } },
                new CNode{Elements = new List<int>{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 } },
                new CNode{Elements = new List<int>{ 0, 1, 1, 0 } },
                new CNode{Elements = new List<int>{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 } },
                new CNode{Elements = new List<int>{ 0, 0, 0, 0 } },
                new CNode{Elements = new List<int>{ 0, 0, 0, 0 } }
            };

            Console.WriteLine("\tGroup by 2:");
            foreach (var group in cNodes.GroupByElements(2))
                Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join("\n", group)}\n");

            Console.WriteLine("\tGroup by 3:");
            foreach (var group in cNodes.GroupByElements(3))
                Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join("\n", group)}\n");

            Console.WriteLine("\tGroup by all:");
            foreach (var group in cNodes.GroupByElements())
                Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join("\n", group)}\n");
        }
    }

    static class CNodeExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<IEnumerable<int>, CNode>> GroupByElements(this IEnumerable<CNode> nodes) =>
            nodes.GroupByElements(nodes.Min(node => node.Elements.Count));

        public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<IEnumerable<int>, CNode>> GroupByElements(this IEnumerable<CNode> nodes, int count) =>
            nodes.GroupBy(node => node.Elements.Take(count), new SequenceCompare());

        private class SequenceCompare : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<int>>
        {
            public bool Equals(IEnumerable<int> x, IEnumerable<int> y) => x.SequenceEqual(y);

            public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<int> obj)
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    var hash = 17;
                    foreach (var i in obj)
                        hash = hash * 23 + i.GetHashCode();
                    return hash;
                }
            }
        }
    }    

    internal class CNode
    {
        public List<int> Elements;

        public override string ToString() => string.Join(", ", Elements);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
        Group by 2:
0, 0, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0

0, 1, 1, 0
0, 1, 1, 0, 0

        Group by 3:
0, 0, 1, 1, 1

0, 0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0

0, 1, 1, 0
0, 1, 1, 0, 0

        Group by all:
0, 0, 1, 1, 1

0, 0, 0, 1, 1

0, 1, 1, 0
0, 1, 1, 0, 0

0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: This will crash if one of the CNodes have a null value for Elements. After all: it wasn't specified that all CNodes have a non-null Elements.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I want to group it by all elements

The solution given by Alex will only group by a limited number of elements. You said you want to group it by all elements, even if you have a CNode with 100 elements. Besides: his solution also crashes if property Elements of one of the CNodes equals null.

So let's create a solution that meets your requirement.

The return value will be a sequence of groups, where every group has a Key, which is a sequence of CNodes. All elements in the group are all source CNodes that have a property Elements equal to the Key.

With equal you mean SequenceEqual. So Elements[0] == Key[0] and Elements[1] == Key[1], etc.

And of course, you want to decide when Elements[0] equals Key[0]: do you want to compare by reference (same object)? or are two CNodes equal if they have the same property values? Or do you want to specify a `IEqualityComparer<CNode>`, so that you can see they are equal if they have the same Name or Id?

```
// overload without IEqualityComparer, calls the overload with IEqualityComparer:
IEnumerable<IGrouping<IEnumerable<Cnode>, CNode>> GroupBy(
    this IEnumerable<CNode> cNodes)
{
    return GroupBy(cNodes, null);
}

// overload with IEqualityComparer; use default CNode comparer if paramer equals null
IEnumerable<IGrouping<IEnumerable<Cnode>, CNode>> GroupBy(
    this IEnumerable<CNode> cNodes,
    IEqualityComparer<CNode> cNodeComparer)
{
    // TODO: check cNodes != null
    if (cNodeComparer == null) cNodeComparer = EqualityComparer<CNode>.Default;

    CNodeSequenceComparer nodeSequenceComparer = new CNodeSequenceComparer()
    {
        CNodeComparer = cNodeComparer,
    }
    return sequenceComparer.GroupBy(nodeSequenceComparer);
}
```

You've noticed I've transferred my problem to a new EqualityComparer: this compare takes two sequences of CNodes and declares them equal if they `SequenceEqual`, using the provided `IEqualityComparer<CNode>`:

```
class CNodeSequenceComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<CNode>>
{
    public IEqualityComparer<CNode> CNodeComparer {get; set;}
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<CNode> x, IEnumerable<CNode> y)
    {
        // returns true if same sequence, using CNodeComparer
        // TODO: implement
    }
}
```

One of the things we have to keep in mind, is that your property Elements might have a value null (after all, you didn't specify that this isn't the case)

```
public bool Equals(IEnumerable<CNode> x, IEnumerable<CNode> y)
{
    if (x == null) return y == null; // true if both null
    if (y == null) return false;     // false because x not null

    // optimizations: true if x and y are same object; false if different types
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) return true;
    if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;

    return x.SequenceEquals(y, this.CNodeComparer);
}
```

Comment: __The solution given by Alex will only group by a limited number of elements.__ Actually `cNodes.GroupByElements()` groups by all elements, where all means a number of elements in the shortest sequence.

Comment: Surely you wouldn't want elements with sequence[1, 2] and sequence [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] to end up in the same group do you?

Comment: One can pass any number to cNodes.GroupByElements(count)
or change public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<IEnumerable<int>, CNode>> GroupByElements(this IEnumerable<CNode> nodes) =>
            nodes.GroupByElements(nodes. __Min__ (node => node.Elements.Count)) to public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<IEnumerable<int>, CNode>> GroupByElements(this IEnumerable<CNode> nodes) =>
            nodes.GroupByElements(nodes. __Max__ (node => node.Elements.Count))

Comment: Anyway, @Cotur in his comment on the question confirmed the collections are of the same size.